# Bind MediaStreamSource to MediaElement

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have a `MediaStreamSource` which is generated dynamically and I want to bind to a MediaElement. Unfortunately the `Source` property accepts only URIs, so I am out of luck.

There is a method `SetSource` which I can call in the code behind, but i have no idea how to do it while maintaining the MVVM pattern.

Does anyone have a method for me to bind a MediaElement to a source?

**Solution (Thanks to Claus Jorgensen)**

I define a class `MainPageLoaded` for use as a message class.

```
public class MainPageLoaded
{
    public MediaStreamSource StreamSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I then send my message in my view model

```
var msg = new MainPageLoaded(){ StreamSource = new MediaStreamSource()};
Messenger.Default.Send<MainPageLoaded>(msg);
```

and receive it in my view

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MainPageLoaded>(this, (action) => SetSoundSource(action));
```

before handling it

```
private void SetSoundSource(MainPageLoaded action)
{
    SoundElement.SetSource(action.StreamSource);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use CommandParameter to pass MediaElement to ViewModel and set media source in viewModel:

```
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        PlayPreviewCommand= new DelegateCommand(PlayPreview, CanPlayPreview);
    }

    public ICommand PlayPreviewCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void PlayPreview(object par)
    {
        if (par != null && par is MediaElement)
        {
            var preview = composition.GeneratePreviewMediaStreamSource(640, 480);
            (par as MediaElement).SetMediaStreamSource(preview);
            (par as MediaElement).Play();
        }
    }
```

and in Xaml View

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play"
                      Label="Play"
                      Command="{Binding PlayPreviewCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mediaElement}">
```

Answer (score 1):

> but i have no idea how to do it while maintaining the MVVM pattern.

Event aggregation. Most, if not all, MVVM frameworks have a Messenger or Event Aggregator, allowing you to Publish and Subscribe to custom events.

In MVVM Light, you would do:

Publish (from ViewModel):

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new MediaStreamSource(...));
```

Subscribe (in your View)

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MediaStreamSource>(this, source => { element.SetSource(source); })
```

Comment: I'm currently using MVVM light, so that is extremely helpful!

Comment: With the newer version of MVVM light, you no longer need to derive from MessageBase. Anything can be sent via a messenger.